# Facebook API: Can I Invite A Test User To My Application?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I'm trying to create test users (works) and then invite them to my app so I could test whether I could retrieve the tracking data (inside the data field). Unfortunately, when I send an invite to a test user I get an exception:

> API Error Code: 2
>
> API Error Description: Service
>   temporarily unavailable
>
> Error Message: Service temporarily
>   unavailable

Here's my code:

```
<input type="text" value="@ViewBag.TestId" id="theId" />

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : '193005690721590',
          status  : true,
          cookie  : true,
          xfbml   : true
        });
    };
    console.log(@ViewBag.TestId);
  $('#sendReq').click(sendRequest);
    function sendRequest() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Invitation to the test application!',
            title: 'Send your friends an application request',
            to: $('#theId').val(),
            data: 'someCode'
        },
        function (response) {
            if (response && response.request_ids) {
                var requests = response.request_ids.join(',');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Parse',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: response,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.result === 'ok') {
                            alert("Everything went fine");
                            //top.location.href = '/Home/About';
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert('canceled');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());
</script>
```

My code is getting the correct ID of the test user and then I'm trying to send the invite but with no success...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sending the request from another test account?

Comment: @echeese: No, I'm sending it from my own account.

Comment: That may be your issue. Test users and regular users are completely cordoned off from each other.

Comment: @echeese: So do you have any idea how I can get one test user to invite another? The first one needs to have the app already installed I believe...

Comment: You could log in as a test user and do your invite, or http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ says you can make a test user with the app already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may be due to you trying to invite the test user from your own account. One of their limitations as listed on the [Test Users](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) docs is "Test users can interact with other test users only and not with real users on site."

Comment: You were right. I'm doing everything manually now and it works for me. I'm still facing one last issue, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043025/facebook-c-sdk-traverse-the-jsonarray-to-get-the-value-of-tracking-data