# Facebook C# SDK: Traverse The JsonArray To Get The Value of Tracking Data

Tags: c#, json, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

This is a followup to:

[(OAuthException) (#15) The method you are calling must be called with an app secret signed session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990051/oauthexception-15-the-method-you-are-calling-must-be-called-with-an-app-secr)

[C# equivalent of file_get_contents (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037356/c-equivalent-of-file-get-contents-php)

[Facebook API: Can I Invite A Test User To My Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041548/facebook-api-can-i-invite-a-test-user-to-my-application)

So I'm at the final step now. I managed to invite users and get the request info once the invited user accepts the invitation. Now I need to traverse the result object (JsonArray) and get the value of the data field which is the tracking data that is sent with the [Request Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

I've tried using dot syntax to traverse the object and some other things but I couldn't get it. So here's my code (which doesn't work):

```
        dynamic requestInfo = fb.Get("/me/apprequests/");
        if (requestInfo.data.Count > 0)
        {
            //var c = requestInfo.data.data;
            var a = requestInfo[0]["data"];
            ViewData.Add("TrackingData", "the value");
        }
```

And here's the result:

> {"data":[{"id":"1001200425907","application":{"name":"MyFirstTestApp","id":"193005690721590"},"to":{"name":"Margaret
>   Diibjcfhg
>
> Sadansteinskymanbergwitz","id":"499203687"},"from":{"name":"Nancy
>   Diibjcfhf
>
> Changwitz","id":"499203686"},"data":"someCode","message":"Invitation
>   to the test
>   application!","created_time":"2011-05-
>
> 18T09:31:40+0000"}]}

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with C#, but have you tried requestInfo["data"][0]["data"]?

Comment: @echeese: I cannot thank you enough! That actually worked! Could you post that as an answer so I could accept it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you are looking for is in `requestInfo["data"][0]["data"]` I used the JSONView addon for Firefox to help me traverse the structure to give you the answer, and I recommend it to help you figure out stuff like this in the future.

Comment: I did not even know about this addon! Thanks again! :)